# SVG group dragging with its foreignobject child and allowing its foriengobject child's content to be draggable too using gsap draggable

Tags: draggable, gsap

I am using gsap draggable to achieve svg group dragging with its content (contains foreignObject) and allowing its contents (contents inside foreignObject) to be draggable independent too.

what I want to achieve is when dragging grey box, its content (cyan colored cell) should be dragged as well and also allow me to drag only cyan cells as well.

if I comment child dragging functionality then parent-child dragging works but when I add child dragging, it's not working as expected.

the code written below is based on an example I found on gsap's form.

```js
Draggable.create('.node-container');

Draggable.create('.tablecelldiv', {
  onPress: function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

```css
.tablecelldiv {
 
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/utils/Draggable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<svg width="900" height="250">
  <g class="node-container">
   <rect height="290" width="290" fill="grey"></rect>
        <foreignObject width="230" height="220" y="62" x="12.5" style="overflow: hidden" >
          <div className="tablebodydiv">
            <div class="tablecelldiv">row 1</div>
            <div class="tablecelldiv">row 2</div>
            <div class="tablecelldiv">row 3</div>
            <div class="tablecelldiv">row 4</div>
          </div>
        </foreignObject>
      </g>
</svg>
```

EDIT: I have tested this code on MS Edge and FireFox browsers and it worked perfectly. I believe its a bug either in GSAP or with Google Chrome Implementation.

Comment: This seems to work fine for me in Chrome on Mac now.

Comment: Hi @ZachSaucier, you are right, at the time I created this issue was not working in chrome, dont know if any recent update to chrome fixed this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is no more a valid issue in chrome, dont know if any recent update to chrome fixed this. This was valid when was created and now it seems to be working fine.